Oracle 10g remove unused dbf
I deleted a tablespace that I no longer needed, and I accidentally left out the SQL query to delete the files. The tablespace has been deleted but the DFB has been left in the operating system path.
I was wondering what the best way to delete it would be, since it is taking up unnecessary space.
I have not dared to execute a
rm -f file.dbf

lsof does not indicate that any process is using it, but I think it would be better to do it from the DB itself if possible.
System: RHEL4
Oracle Database: 10.2
Thanks!

Datafiles are only referenced through a tablespace, and there is no way to drop them from the operating system using DDL commands other than the drop tablespace command. If you have dropped the tablespace already without the including contents and datafiles option, then you should be safe to use rm -f file.dbf from the operating system.

Thanks for clarifying my doubt, I removed the dbf without problems from my system.
